# ADFS reply aborts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, adfs

I am trying to setup ADFS for my MVC application.

my site is on https://mysites.domain:336/

When I login I am redirected to ADFS and can authenticate but when it returns me back to https://mysites.domain:336/

it send me to https://mysites.domain/ instead and the network traffic in the browser says that the request was aborted.

I have run out of ideas please help

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...It turns out that in the ADFS Relying Party properties The endpoint was configured without the portnumber